# Leaflet map • trouble porting code from old website

Tags: javascript

I've copied over code from an exciting website (https://romonysetra.no/tomtevelger/) to new website build (WP Divi). But I have no luck getting the code to work on the new site.https://romonysetra.no/divi/tomtevelger/

Any tips on what is wrong or what it not working on the new website build is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<div id="mapid"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://romonysetra.no/tomteData.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mymap = L.map('mapid', { zoomSnap:0,zoomDelta: 0.5}).setView([61.55794889870435, 12.220130837034901], 16);
    L.tileLayer('https://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_gmaps?layers=topo4&zoom={z}&x={x}&y={y}', {
    attribution: '<a href="http://www.kartverket.no/">Kartverket</a>'}).addTo(mymap);
    
    var info = L.control();
    info.onAdd = function (mymap) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};
    // method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Informasjon</h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br/><br/>' + props.pris + '<br/>' + props.status + '<br/>' + props.areal
        : 'Vis tomtedata');
};
info.addTo(mymap);
function getColor(d) {
        return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
                d > 75  ? '#636363' :
                d > 65  ? '#3182bd' :
                d > 35  ? '#276897' :
                d > 25   ? '#de2d26' :
                d > 15   ? '#feb24c' :
                d > 5   ? '#31a354' :
                            '#efedf5';
    }

    function style(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'black',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.farge)
        };
    }
var geojsonTomt;
var geojsonVei;

function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
        layer.setStyle({
        weight: 2,
        color: '#f0f0f0',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
        });
    layer.bringToFront();
    info.update(layer.feature.properties);  
}
function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojsonTomt.resetStyle(e.target);
    info.update();
}
function zoomToFeature(e) {
        mymap.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
}
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature
    });
}
geojsonTomt = L.geoJson(tomteData, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature    
}).addTo(mymap);

geojsonVei = L.geoJson(veiData, {
    style: style
}).addTo(mymap);

</script>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Btw, I'm voting to close this because it doesn't contain a self-contained example to demonstrate the problem. Links to external websites, especially those in development, tend to break or disappear are unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. This was missing form the head of the page.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<style>
#mapid { width: 1200px; height: 800px; }.info {
    padding: 6px 8px;
    font: 16px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: white;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.info h4 {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    color: #777;
}
 .text-labels {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 700;
            /* Use color, background, set margins for offset, etc */
        }
</style>
```